# WP Super Cache -- delete cache for home page once a day

Tags: caching, wordpress

The goal:

```
The cache for homepage will regenerated once a day.
```

Possible solution:
Those function with some time checking could work.

```
$files_to_delete = get_all_supercache_filenames( $dir );
prune_super_cache( get_supercache_dir() . '/index.html' );
```

The problem:
When there some cache exists even **Must Use Plugin**'s do not get executed.

I tried that but the site works fine. :(

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Homepage Cache Cleaner
 * Description: Clear cache for homepage once a day.
 * Version: 1.0
 */

 die();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cronjob`!
You can make a script run at a specific interval.